# Lambda function handler executing DynamoDB update twice

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

My Lambda function is supposed to increment a value in a dynamodb table, I'm using the .update API as an atomic counter.
The value is incremented twice! I tried to change the increment variable value and it always increments twice.
For example: the value in my DynamoDB table is 2, and the increment value is 1. I test the Lambda function, and the dynamoDB value is 4 (instead of 3).

The same code (without the handler function) works successfully from outside Lambda (executed from VSCode using the JS SDK)
What could be the issue?

```
'use strict';

const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({ region: "me-central-1" });

const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
await docClient.update(
  {
    TableName: "visitor-counter-table",
    Key: {
      "visitor-counter": "counter",
    },
    UpdateExpression: "set #num = #num + :incr",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#num": "number",
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":incr": 1,
    },
  },
  (err, data) => {
    err ? console.log(err) : console.log(data);
  }
).promise();

  return {"statusCode": 200, "body": "number added to DDB Success"}
};
```

Here is the code i ran on VSCode:

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({ region: "me-central-1" });

const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

docClient.update(
  {
    TableName: "visitor-counter-tbl",
    Key: {
      "visitor-counter": "counter",
    },
    UpdateExpression: "set #num = #num + :incr",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#num": "number",
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":incr": 1,
    },
  },
  (err, data) => {
    err ? console.log(err) : console.log(data);
  }
);
```

Comment: Can you please exactly show the code that you ran locally (i.e. without the handler function)?

Comment: ^ done, updated the question @ErmiyaEskandary

Comment: How do you trigger the lambda?

Comment: @BorislavStoilov for this purpose i use the TEST button in lambda, but i also trigger it using an API Gateway URL, which yields the same result.

Comment: Try removing `(err, data) => {
    err ? console.log(err) : console.log(data);
  }` from the Lambda function code and retry again - let me know if that works

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Thanks! it worked. I have no idea though why would the callback cause this trouble.

Comment: @b_a9f It's because you're awaiting the promise, and using the callback at the same time - that's 2x. You should either await the promise OR use the callback not await the promise AND use the callback. I'll type up an answer soon :) glad it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing success and failure callbacks to `docClient.update` while also obtaining and awaiting a generated promise.

This means that ultimately you're triggering the update *twice*.

The reason why your local invocation works is that you're only passing the callbacks, and not asking for a promise (`.promise()`) and then awaiting it. This results in triggering the update *once*.

Either use await, or use callbacks - **not both**.

This should work:

```js
await docClient.update(
  {
    TableName: "visitor-counter-table",
    Key: {
      "visitor-counter": "counter",
    },
    UpdateExpression: "set #num = #num + :incr",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#num": "number",
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":incr": 1,
    },
  }
).promise();
```

Comment: It's interesting. I wonder why this is happening. Why would providing both a callback function and requesting a promise result in 2x API requests? That seems like a bug in the AWS SDK, or at least a very questionable outcome that would be worth preventing, if possible. Two completions from 1x API request (one a fulfilled promise and the other a callback) I could almost understand but not 2x API requests. Might have to dig into the code here to understand more.

Comment: OK, a call to `service.action(params)` returns an [AWSRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html) object that you have to call `.send()` on in order for the API request to actually be sent. But a call to `service.action(params, callback)` actually executes `if (callback) request.send(callback)`, so the presence of the callback function sends the API request. Now, the `.promise()` method's code "sends the request and returns a promise", so it also sends the request. And that's why the API call happens twice if callback and promise() are both present.